# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:143)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to using react native to build the application, i tried to display an array using flatlist, it can successfully show the data, but the warning message are shown.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Directory for "" doesn't exist. Please make sure directory '' exists before calling downloadAsync.]
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:104:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:105:17 in downloadAsync
at node_modules/expo-file-system/build/FileSystem.js:101:7 in downloadAsync
at node_modules/expo-asset/build/PlatformUtils.js:49:25 in _downloadAsyncManagedEnv
```

and my code is below

```
       <View>
 
 <FlatList
          data = {result}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.Code}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
        <View>

          <List.Item
    title={item.Title}
    description={item.Code}

>
</List.Item>


        </View>  
        
        }
          />


              </View>
```

Comment: I got this error (only on iOS, not Android) after adding the library `@expo/vector-icons` on a Expo project and showing an icon to the UI. I fixed it by stopping the development server and starting it again, and also reseting the iOS emulator (Device -> Erase All Content and Settings...). I don't think reseting is required though.

Comment: `Device -> Erase All Content and Settings...` works to me

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your iPhone simulator and do the following:

```
Device -> Erase All Content and Settings
```

Then restart your server and start it up again using the expo go app, you should be good to go.